# Using two SQL Server instances

Tags: sql-server

I have two SQL Server services running on my server - `MSSQLSERVER` and `SQLEXPRESS`:

[image]

- `MSSQLSERVER` runs on static TCP port
- `SQLEXPRESS` runs on dynamic TCP port

I do connect from remote machine using Management Studio. I can connect to `SQLEXPRESS` by entering server name- `GM\SQLEXPRESS`.

I can connect to `MSSQLSERVER` by entering server just PC name - `GM` without instance name, but I can't connect using instance name `GM\MSSQLSERVER`.

Why do I need to provide instance name for `SQLEXPRESS` while I can't use it in `MSSQLSERVER` case ?

Answer (score 1):

`MSSQLSERVER` is the **default, unnamed instance** - of which there can only be one on any machine, and since it's the **default** instance, you connect to it by using just the **machine name** (or `.`, `(local)`, or `localhost` if it's running on your own machine).

That's just the way Microsoft designed and built it.

Any **other** instance you want must have a separate, distinct name - and in that case, you **must use** that instance name (together with the machine name) to connect to it - `SQLEXPRESS` is just one example, you can name your instance anything you like (as long as it's a valid instance name and not `MSSQLSERVER` :-)